# MS Access in query: The expression you entered contains invalid-syntax

Tags: database, ms-access, syntax

I have this error message:
*You omitted a operand or operator, you entered an invalid character or comma, or you entered text without surrounding it in quotation marks.*

Here is a picture about my problem:
[image]

I want to format my "BYDAY" query and they have a problem with this: `BYDAY: Format([SDÁTUM],"ddd")` and i got this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your local *separator* is semicolon:

```
BYDAY: Format([SDÁTUM];"ddd")
```